# Better EJS error debugging

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am getting this error from EJS:

```
TypeError: /Users/danypelletier/Development/CleanBite/views/pages/index.ejs:68
    66|     <div class="container">
    67|         <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
 >> 68|             <h3><%= translations.customizePlan[language] %></h3>
    69|             <img src="images/border.png" alt="">
    70|         </div>
    71|         <div class="customize">

Cannot read property 'en' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/danypelletier/Development/CleanBite/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:464:12), <anonymous>:57:54)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/danypelletier/Development/CleanBite/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:464:12), <anonymous>:69:9)
    at returnedFn (/Users/danypelletier/Development/CleanBite/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:493:17)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/danypelletier/Development/CleanBite/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:350:31)
    at View.render (/Users/danypelletier/Development/CleanBite/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:126:8)
    at tryRender (/Users/danypelletier/Development/CleanBite/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:639:10)
    at EventEmitter.render (/Users/danypelletier/Development/CleanBite/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:591:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/danypelletier/Development/CleanBite/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
    at /Users/danypelletier/Development/CleanBite/app.js:29:13
    at /Users/danypelletier/Development/CleanBite/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:726:13
```

`translations.customizePlan.en` definitely exists.
Regardless, when I take out the line `<%= translations.customizePlan[language] %>`, a new error appears, now being:

```
TypeError: /Users/danypelletier/Development/CleanBite/views/pages/index.ejs:68
   66|     <div class="container">
   67|         <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
>> 68|             <h3></h3>
   69|             <img src="images/border.png" alt="">
   70|         </div>
   71|         <div class="customize">

Cannot read property 'en' of undefined
```

Which now is an error that doesn't make much sense to me, pointing at an innocent `h3`.

Any help on how I can debug this well?

Comment: I had an undefined property being called several lines before (typo).
My question still applies, would be better if EJS pointed where the error actually is. Maybe the guys at EJS are working on that for a next version.

Comment: Might be better to ask them directly: https://github.com/mde/ejs/issues